# Force Grails to use message.properties with correct Language Code?

Tags: grails, internationalization

I use `message.properties`for [i18n](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/guide/i18n.html). I have the the following property files.

```
message.properties
message_de.properties
```

This works fine when I do something like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("de")
def test = g.message(code:'some.code', locale: locale)
```

The problem is when I use a `Locale` like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("de_DE")
```

In the former case Grails searches for a property file `message_de_DE.properties` which does not exist so it falls back to `message.properties`.

**How can I force Grails to do the following?**

1. Check if there is a `properties` file which matches the requested Language code and Country code of the  Locale.
2. Check if there is a `properties` file which matches the requested Language code
3. If 1. and 2. fails fall back to `message.properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changing

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("de_DE")
```

to

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE")
```

should achieve what you want.

AFAIK Grails by default does what you mentioned in your points, there is no need to force.

The single argument constructor of `Locale` expects the argument to be a language name, but *de_DE* is not a valid language name (This may be the reason grails falls back to `message.properties`). You have to use the other variant of the constructors which take language name as the first argument and country name as the second. The [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

`Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE")` works fine.

Can use these ways also.

```
Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("de").setRegion("DE").build();
```

Here use dash(-) instead of underscore (_)

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("de-DE");
```